# Rabbit is losing chunks of hair in different areas

Tags: health, rabbits, skin-condition, hairloss, wound-care

This rabbit was bought in a pet store. After a month, we started to notice that a part of his skin is going bald, which we assumed to be harmless. However, we were alarmed to see that the baldness started spreading in different areas of his body. The bald spots have crusty dandruff scales that were not moving (we searched and most of the answers were mites that look like moving dandruff scales). Anyone out there who knows what this is? And how to cure it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the wounded regions in point of contact with the cage, or does it have wounds in back of its body also? My two dogs play fight each other and get these type of wounds but not too much. Is the rabbit active? If not, pecking birds like crows can peck him and these wounds could occur that way.

Comment: There are too many causes for bald spots. Injuries, allergies, over licking (caused by different things), herpes virus and so on. Please see a vet!

Comment: There are no wounds in the back of his body. I had observed that the bald spots occur in areas where there are joints, i.e. the boundary between the arms and the shoulders, the legs and the hipbone, the groin.. also, he has not interacted with any animals.

Comment: The described areas are more wet/damp than the others. This speaks for some kind of infection of bacteria/virus or even fungus. You need the advice of a vet! They can make tests and give you the propper treatment for the detected infection.

Comment: Please let us know, how your rabbit is. What did the vet say?

Comment: oh hey! we already figured it out without talking to the vet haha. the thing is, i got ringworms,, and no one in our house has ringworms. which would mean i got it form the rabbit. the rabbit is safe and sound right now!

Comment: would you please answer your own question? This would help other users with the same problem :)